# Transition not working in Firefox or opera, just chrome

Tags: css, css-transitions

This is my CSS:

```
#pays li{
list-style:none;
margin-left:44px;
display:block;
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
background:url('http://symbolset.com/images/paypal-logo.png') no-repeat;
transition:0.2s;
-moz-transition:0.2s;
-webkit-transition:0.2s;
-o-transition:0.2s;
background-size:300px 180px;
}
#pays li:hover{background:url('http://data-informed.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/PayPal_logo.svg-crop-300x180.png') no-repeat}
#paypal{width:300px;height:180px}​
```

Here is the [full code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMq3A/). It work perfect in Chrome, all other browsers not working.

Comment: hm, doesn't look too nice in chrome either. And theoretically there is nothing to animate on an url-change. Perhaps it's a glitch in chrome?

Comment: I need to make fade in between tow images, its good and smooth in chrome

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Christoph Unfortunately I did not find a solution

Comment: Have you tried one of my ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`background-size` was not animatable in an earlier draft of the "CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3". I guess it's just not yet implemented across browsers. But in fact [it should be animatable as of the draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) ("Animatable: yes except keyword values").

Always remember that both, the backgrounds and the transitions modules are not finished yet. The "CSS Backgrounds and Borders Level 3" is at "Candidate Recommendation" status and "CSS Transitions" are just a "Working Draft". So you are using instable technologies that bay be subject of further changes. Don't trust what Chromium had already implemented, it may change.

A list of animatable properties in CSS: http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/

Overview on CSS development statuses: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

Comment: it's not the size which needed to be animated (size itself is not very well supported atm), but the url-change which is even worse.

Comment: @Christoph Whoops, sorry – but the reason might be the same. CSS Transitions is only a working draft right now.

Answer (score 0):

As transitions on background-image changes are so pooly supported atm, you have 2 options:

1. use an imagesprite and animate the background-position
2. embed another element (unfortunately you can't use pseudo-elements, animations on them are very poorly supported too, atm) and animate opacity